# VB script to rename all files in dir to start with an index

Tags: vbscript

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = "."

Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
Set files = folder.Files
Set index = 1
For each folderIdx In files
File.Move Replace(File.Path,folderIdx ,index) 
index = index + 1
Next
```

This doesnt work.. Whats the problem in this script?

**EDIT:**
Working script. I need the filenames to be "001", "002", ... etc instead of just "1", "2"..

```
Dim oFS  : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sDir : sDir     = "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\icons\"
  Dim nIdx : nIdx     = 1
  Dim oFile
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder(sDir).Files
      If oFS.FileExists(oFS.BuildPath(sDir, nIdx&"."&oFile.Name)) Then
         WScript.StdOut.WriteLine " already exists"
      Else
         oFile.Name = nIdx&"."&oFile.Name
      End If
      nIdx       = nIdx + 1
  Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem: You use `File` for the .Move and in the Replace call, but your `For Each` loop gives you the current file object in the variable named `folderIdx`.

Your Replace would result in just the intended file name, and probably move the file to the current folder (as seen by the FS). (I did not test this speculation)

To rename/renumber all files in a folder according to an increasing index, I'd use:

```
  Dim oFS  : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sDir : sDir     = "..\testdata\17165630"
  Dim nIdx : nIdx     = 1
  Dim oFile
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder(sDir).Files
      WScript.Echo "bad idea:", Replace(oFile.Path, oFile, nIdx)
      WScript.StdOut.Write oFile.Name
      If oFS.FileExists(oFS.BuildPath(sDir, nIdx)) Then
         WScript.StdOut.WriteLine " already exists"
      Else
         oFile.Name = nIdx
         WScript.StdOut.WriteLine " => " & oFile.Name
      End If
      nIdx = nIdx + 1 ' Thanks, @Ansgar!
  Next
```

The output:

```
bad idea: 1
5 => 1
bad idea: 2
6 => 2
bad idea: 3
8 => 3
bad idea: 4
7 => 4
```

should make you cautious as to the order before and after the renumber action.

**Update:**

To prepend zeros, use somethink like:

```
>> For Each nIdx In Array(1, 5, 10, 99, 100, 999)
>>     WScript.Echo Right(1000 + nIdx, 3)
>> Next
>>
001
005
010
099
100
999
```

To keep a specific order, you'll have to process the files in that order. I'd start with shelling out to `dir /o:<your choice>`.

**Update II:**

A .FileExists check can't avoid renumbering an already renumbered file. You must look at the oFile.Name of the current file and skip it, if it was already processed. If you have non-numerical file names in the beginning, you can use `IsNumeric()`:

```
  Dim oFS  : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sDir : sDir     = "..\testdata\17165630"
  Dim nIdx : nIdx     = 1
  Dim oFile
  WScript.Echo "----- Given:"
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder(sDir).Files
      WScript.Echo oFile.Path
  Next
  WScript.Echo "----- Rename:"
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder(sDir).Files
      WScript.StdOut.Write oFile.Name
      If IsNumeric(Left(oFile.Name, 3)) Then
         WScript.Stdout.WriteLine " is already numbered"
      Else
         Dim sNewName : sNewName = Right(1000 + nIdx, 3) & "." & oFile.Name
         If oFS.FileExists(oFS.BuildPath(sDir, sNewName)) Then
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine " already exists"
         Else
            oFile.Name = sNewName
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine " => " & oFile.Name
         End If
         nIdx = nIdx + 1
      End If
  Next
  WScript.Echo "----- Result:"
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder(sDir).Files
      WScript.Echo oFile.Path
  Next
```

Output of two runs:

```
----- Given:
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\c.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\a.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\b.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\d.png
----- Rename:
c.png => 001.c.png
a.png => 002.a.png
b.png => 003.b.png
d.png => 004.d.png
----- Result:
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\002.a.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\003.b.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\004.d.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\001.c.png

----- Given:
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\002.a.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\003.b.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\004.d.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\001.c.png
----- Rename:
002.a.png is already numbered
003.b.png is already numbered
004.d.png is already numbered
001.c.png is already numbered
----- Result:
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\002.a.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\003.b.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\004.d.png
M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\17165630\001.c.png
```

Comment: `nIdx` should be incremented outside the conditional, otherwise incrementation will stop once a name conflict is encountered.

Comment: Thanks for response. Its throwing error at "oFile.Name = nIdx".. error is "The handle is invalid"

Comment: @user2432627 - then you don't use (an equivalent to) the code I posted; double check and/or post your code.

Comment: Im able to get all files renamed.. Now another issue is sort order.. i need the files to be named "001" "002" "003" ... "010"... "100"...

Comment: I think the check for FileExists is not working.. it renames even if the file already present the same name.. if there is a "001.a.png" it renames it to "001.001.a.png"..