# prepend all files in a selected directory with a number and a preceding 0

Tags: shell, vbscript, directory, rename

I've found an issue with adobes bates numbering tool, where file names are messing up the order in which they are numbered. I was hoping to write a script that users would be able to click on and add the folder extension for all the files. Then the script would prepend all the file names within the folder with a `000001filename.pdf`, `000002filename.pdf`, etc.

I've never combined scripts before but I've found scripts that either rename OR prepend, and I couldn't find anything that would rename sequentially with preceding 0s.

This is what I have so far:

```vbs
Dim iloop As Integer
Dim iFileNumber As Integer

Dim sPrefix As String
Dim sNewFileName As String
Dim arr() As String
'Get array of all pdfs from the selected directory
arr = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*.PDF")
'loop through the array
For iloop = 0 To UBound(arr)
  'Create a prefix for each file
  iFileNumber = iloop + 1
  Select Case iFileNumber
    Case 0 To 9 : sPrefix = "00000" & iFileNumber
    Case 10 To 99 : sPrefix = "0000" & iFileNumber
    Case 100 To 999 : sPrefix = "000" & iFileNumber
    Case 1000 To 9999 : sPrefix = "00" & iFileNumber
    Case 10000 To 99999 : sPrefix = "0" & iFileNumber
    Case Else : sPrefix = iFileNumber
  End Select
  Dim arr2() As String
  'split the path by the / symbol to get the filename
  arr2 = Split(arr(iloop),"\")
  'Add the prefix to the front of the filename, filename will be the last item in the array.
  arr2(uBound(arr2)) = sPrefix & arr2(uBound(arr2))
  'Put the new path and filename back together
  sNewFileName = Join(arr2,"\")
  'Rename the file with the new filename
  System.IO.File.Move(arr(iloop),sNewFileName)
Next
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17166348/603855 to see a solution for your problem using *VBScript*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VBScript solution for renaming PDF files in a given folder by prefixing them with a running number, left-padded with zeroes, could look like this:

```vbs
fldr = "..."

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

i = -1
For Each f In fso.GetFolder(fldr).Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "pdf" Then
    Do
      i = i + 1
      newname = Right("0000" & i, 5) & f.Name
    Loop While fso.FileExists(fso.BuildPath(f.ParentFolder, newname))
    f.Name = newname
  End If
Next
```