# VBS: For-each loop (sometimes) iterates through file collection indefinitely

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

The goal of the following VBscript is to prepend a user-defined string to all files with a particular extension within a specified directory:

```
directory = "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\Test\"   'include final backslash
extension = ".doc"  'include period, ex: ".tab"
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

addStr = InputBox("Enter the text you would like to prepend:", , "xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_x_xx_xxx_")


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(directory)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each file In colFiles
    absPath = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(file)
    currentExtension = objFSO.GetExtensionName(absPath)
    If  StrComp(currentExtension, Mid(extension, 2)) = 0 Then
        file.Name = addStr & objFSO.GetFileName(file)
    End If
Next
```

The script generally works well, but occasionally demonstrates this *problematic behavior*:

When running the script on a directory with lots of files and/or with files with long names, the script appears to iterate back over the collection of files (i.e. prepends to files that have already been prepended) and does so until the filenames become too long to be recognized by the FSO, crashing the script.

The threshold of the number of files/length of filenames at which this occurs appears to be very distinct and reproducible. For example, if I create a target directory (e.g. "...\Desktop\Test") with a file named '1.doc' that is copied/pasted several times, the script will properly rename up to 31 files, but it demonstrates the problematic behavior with 32+ files. Similarly, if I run the script twice over 31 files (generated in the same manner), the script demonstrates the problematic behavior on the second run.

Any thoughts as to the underlying issue are very much appreciated--thanks in advance!

Comment: This existing question is very relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165630/vb-script-to-rename-all-files-in-dir-to-start-with-an-index

Answer (score 2):

You may have issues here because you're modifying files *while* iterating them. Try creating an array of file names first and then iterate over the array, changing the names.

```
ReDim a(colFiles.Count - 1)
i = 0

For Each File In colFiles
    a(i) = File.Path
    i = i + 1
Next

For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    If StrComp(objFSO.GetExtensionName(a(i)), Mid(extension, 2)) = 0 Then
        With objFSO.GetFile(a(i))
            .Name = addStr & .Name
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the above behaviour occurs is, because when you initially call `Set colFiles = objFolder.Files`, the first 32 files are retrieved, and placed into a cache.  Once those 32 files are processed, then the system retrieves the first 32 filenames which have not been processed yet.

Since you have renamed the files after the initial call, the system sees those as new filenames that have not been processed yet.  Since their names are still first alphabetically, they are placed into the 32-file cache, and processed again.

The solution by @Bond is the standard workaround for this issue.  Due to limitations of vbs, this is the only practical resolution of this issue.